# Problems calling magento API

Tags: magento

I’m calling the Magento (1.3.1.1) API http://MAGENTO/api/v2_soap?wsdl . And I’m getting Access Denied Soap exceptions when I call the Login method.

**I have created a webservice user called Admin and assigned them to a role that has access to ‘ALL’.**

I have another instance of Magento hosted on the same server and it works fine, and I have asked a colleague to give it a try, setting up their own user and calling the webservice and they experience the same problem.

**EDIT:**I tried starting from scratch again, reapplying my changes and testing at each stage. Iv managed to pin it down to something in the database as the error occurs again when I re-import the database. So I know its nothing to do with any code or template changes I have made. Still lost though!

Comment: I solved this by rebuilding the site - which was not fun

Comment: If your using the latest version of Magento 1.3 and still have issues, check out the fix here: http://www.everythingilike.com/magento-api-bug-fixes